# Which relation between database tables will be proper?

Tags: mysql, database

We have a database, which keeps informations about music - we have e.g. table for artists, bands, songs, albums etc. The next step is to allow users to rate those things, using 10-point grading scale.

What is the best way to remember all of users ratings? Surely I can create simple table, that contains user_id, rating_value and rated_thing_element, but obviously I can't join it to EVERY table.

Is it better then, to create, for example, one table called `ratings` and few additional tables, like ratings_albums, ratings_songs, ratings_bands etc. to bind, or maybe just few `ratingsXXX` tables for each of elements I've mentioned above?

I'm not sure which way I should go... or does it really matter.=?

Comment: How often will you query the database, how many users will use it, how many records will each table hold, etc? These are all factors in whether you'd want a normalized (your first example) or denormalized (more data replication so less joins) database.

Comment: Well, database will be queried very often, as it contains all the informations that users can get on the website. It's hard to say 'how many users will use it', but let's take quiet extreme value - like few thousands (brave words!). Those tables will hold thousands of values, due to the music development. At first thought, I was sure the first example is way better, but then I get some doubts... however, seems to me it's the best option. Do you have any guides?

Comment: In fact, you could have a single `Rating` table and referential integrity. Look for supertype/subtype pattern and related questions. It would require an `Element` table that is the supertype and all tables that need ratings would be the subtypes.

Comment: @JanuszKobiela Start with a normalized database, and when you see that any of your queries are taking too long start denormalizing. Also, look into indexes if you haven't already. Check out this blog post http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/04/denormalization-patterns.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal preference is to go with a normalized table and strict foreign references. So I would use artist_ratings, album_ratings, and song_ratings tables. To make queries easier, I would create views to represent the most often joined tables.

You can use a ratings table with no foreign keys (well except for the user reference), but you lose referential integrity enforcement. This table would be

```
ratings {
  id integer,
  userId integer, -- FK to users table
  referenceId integer, -- This is not a FK, but will contain the ID of the artist/album/song
  type char, -- a = album, A = artist, s = song
  rating int
}
```

Comment: I thought about it at the beginning, but the idea of 'type' column doesn't look good to me... However, I like your personal preferences, as it's just what seems to me was the best. It makes me a little bit more certain about this choice!

Comment: I threw it out there as something you "can" do. It's definitely not something I would ever consider. I was on a contract last year where they had used this concept and it was nothing but trouble.